# Problem with broadcasting and websocket in Laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, real-time, laravel-8, broadcasting

I don't understand where it is blocking. If I replace the `update()` with a `create()` method, it works, or if I remove the broadcast, the update works. How to update with the broadcast?

> Call to a member function load() on bool

```php
public function SendToMarket(Request $request, $id)
{
    $card = auth()->user()->cards()->findOrFail($id)->update([
            'market_id' => $request["_market"],
            'borderStyle_id' => $request["_borderStyle"],
            'price' => $request["_price"]
        ]
    );

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Card Send to market Successfully !',
        'alert-type' => 'warning'
    );

    broadcast(new FetchCardEvent($card->load('user')))->toOthers();

    return redirect()->route('user.cards')->with($notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update()` does not return the Modal instance. Instead it will return a [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type).

After retrieving the card using `firstOrFail()` you should update it separately.

```php
public function SendToMarket(Request $request, $id) {
    $card = auth()->user()->cards()->findOrFail($id);

    $card->update([
        'market_id' => $request["_market"],
        'borderStyle_id' => $request["_borderStyle"],
        'price' => $request["_price"]
    ]);

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Card Send to market Successfully !',
        'alert-type' => 'warning'
    );

    broadcast(new FetchCardEvent($card->load('user')))->toOthers();

    return redirect()->route('user.cards')->with($notification);
}
```